# it's a correct typescript optional type?

Tags: typescript

```
export default async (port?) => {
    console.log(port)
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA29UGcCeAdgMZwAUksA-AJRwC8AfHAN4BQcncxEhuEmYADpMEAOYVoMGmwC+QA

`port?` without `type` like `port?: number` it's a correct typescript optional type?

but in ts playgroud, without error output

Comment: Well, it's not allowed because you have `noImplicityAny` set to `true` in the typescript compiler options. If you allow implicit any types, then this would compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over it, you'll see what it's doing:

[image]

When you omit the type from a parameter, TypeScript will implicitly infer it to be of type `any`.

This is separate from the indicator of `?`, which tells TS that the parameter is optional.

Your code means: "The function accepts zero or one parameter, which may be of any type."

What you're doing is technically legal with `noImplicitAny`, but using `any` mostly defeats the point of using TypeScript, so it's a good idea to keep `noImplicitAny` on.

Comment: so if i allow any type in tsconfig, `port?` equal `port?: any`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't correct in typescript. you have to specify the type, or use Any

```
export default async (port?:number) => {
    console.log(port)
}
```